# could not update or signout from account - devise_token_auth- Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm using [devise_token_auth](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/devise_token_auth/0.1.37#initializer-settings) for my Rails `Rest Api` . `Register` and `login` work like a charm as routes defined in its documentation . But when i try to do the `sign_out` as specified by documentation . It goes to server and shows me following query and result

> Started DELETE "/auth/sign_out" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-02 11:46:00 
>   +0500 Processing by DeviseTokenAuth::SessionsController#destroy as */*   
> User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`uid`
>   = 'abc@no.com' LIMIT 1 
> Completed 404 Not Found in 2ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)

I pasted the whole functioning in the server where you can see that it's a `delete request` according to [devise_token_auth](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/devise_token_auth/0.1.37#initializer-settings)  documentation . While this user `abc@no.com` is present in db. and `sign in` is working great . 
Like `sign_out` , it's having issue with `updation of account` where i've `put request` same as in documentation .

**Note:**

Header are kept the same as received in sign_in request - Below are the headers

```
access-token wwwww
token-type   Bearer
client       werse
uid          abc@no.com
expiry       4564
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issues using a rails 5 api only server using `config.api_only = true` in `application.rb`.

To get `sign_in` to originally work, I needed to add the first two lines below. To get `sign_out` to work I added the last line.

```
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore
config.middleware.use Rack::MethodOverride
```

I ran `rake middleware` to see the differences between an api server and a full rails server to help figure this out.